# Pythonic way to develop the ~ in a path?

Tags: python, path

(Linux/Python 3.5)
I want to normalize the ~ character in strings like "~/something" and get something like "/home/something/" .

I don't want to use a replacement of my own since I'd like to use a very generalist way to achieve this, using a Python module by example.

Neither [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) neither [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) seem to fit my expectations.

Any idea ?

Comment: `os.path.expanduser` is a way to go.

Comment: You don't need to mark the question solved in the title; simply accepting an answer (as you have done) is sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You apparently missed the [`os.path.expanduser()` function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser):

> On Unix and Windows, return the argument with an initial component of `~` or `~user` replaced by that *user*‘s home directory.